# Networkx - allow duplicate node labels?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-modelling-language

I want to be able to have a lot of nodes have the same label— in my particular case, each node represents a news article, and they should be labelled with their news category. Ultimately, what I *really* want is a GML file with these labels.

Here's a small sample:

```python
Gtest = nx.Graph()
nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
labels = {0:"business", 1:"business",2:"sports", 3:"sports", 4:"politics"}

for node in nodes:
    Gtest.add_node(node)

print Gtest.nodes(data=True) 

""" 
this prints:
[(0, {}), (1, {}), (2, {}), (3, {}), (4, {})]

Which is good, I want 5 nodes.
"""

Gtest = nx.relabel_nodes(Gtest, labels)

print Gtest.nodes(data=True)

"""this prints:

[('business', {}), ('politics', {}), ('sports', {})]

There are only 3 nodes.
"""

nx.write_gml(Gtest, "gml/stackoverflow_test", stringizer = None)

"""
This writes the GML file:

graph [
  name "()"
  node [
    id 0
    label "business"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "politics"
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "sports"
  ]
]
"""
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to end up with the GML file:

```
graph [
  name "()"
  node [
    id 0
    label "business"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "business"
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "sports"
  ]
  node [
    id 3
    label "sports"
  ]
  node [
    id 4
    label "politics"
  ]
]
```

Is it possible to have the same label for multiple nodes/to generate this output file?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to have the same label for multiple nodes/to generate this output file?

Comment: Why don't you try? (Hint: yes, it is possible.)

Comment: I've been trying for quite a while! I feel like there's something obvious I'm overlooking, maybe I have a gap in understanding about how networkx works? I'm largely confused as to why relabel_nodes is combining nodes with the same label.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how this can be done:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, {'label' : 'foo'})
G.add_node(2, {'label' : 'foo'})
G.nodes(data=True)
#[(1, {'label': 'foo'}), (2, {'label': 'foo'})]
nx.write_gml(G,open("foo.gml","wb"))
```

> graph [
>         node [
>           id 0
>           label 1
>         ]
>         node [
>           id 1
>           label 2
>         ]
>       ]

**NB** The answer is for `networkx-1.1`. It does not work in 2.0 or above. Instead, you can set node attrribute:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {1: 'foo', 2: 'foo'}, 'label')
G.nodes(data=True)
#NodeDataView({1: {'label': 'foo'}, 2: {'label': 'foo'}})
```

Comment: Problem is, for me at least, when you want to do this to an existing graph. (For example, I want to use a graph generator _then_ relabel the nodes. relabel_nodes() appears to add_node() using the new label as the first parameter.

Comment: @RhodriM The answer is given for networkx-1.1. It does not work in 2.0 and above because the versions are not compatible. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks DYZ, that looks great.

Going to ask on the networkx github board about whether relabel_nodes or your original example _should_ (or not) do this in the newer versions.

Comment: Actually, no, this doesn't work. It appears you're adding label to node data. Not updating the label itself, and on writing gml you get the same labels as the ids as always.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing a custom function as the `stringizer` argument to the  [write_gml](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gml.write_gml.html#networkx.readwrite.gml.write_gml) function.

Here is a code that produces a GML file that you want:

```js
import networkx as nx

class Article:
    def __init__(self, id, category):
        self.id = id
        self.category = category

    def get_category(self):
        return self.category

Gtest = nx.Graph()
nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
labels = {0: "business", 1: "business", 2: "sports", 3: "sports", 4: "politics"}

for node in nodes:
    Gtest.add_node(Article(node, labels[node]))

nx.write_gml(Gtest, "articles.gml", stringizer=Article.get_category)
```

Please note that if the object that you add to the graph in `add_node` is an int, float, or dict, then the stringizer function will NOT be called. Therefore, the code above uses a custom class for nodes.